# Materials for McBride's Freshman Organic Chemistry at Yale University

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond

I have been looking over the online Organic Chemistry course taught by McBride at Yale and named "Freshman Organic Chemistry", 125A, which is on Itunes University.  Only the lectures are online; and McBride regularly refers to his website as the source of additional materials. Looking at the exams it turns out that much of the course material must be on his webpages, which are no longer available on the specified website since he retired.  Can I find similar materials somewhere?

Answer (score 10):

Most materials are available for the fall 2010 at
http://chem125.webspace.yale.edu/indexFall10.html

and for Spring 2011 (the last time the course was given)
http://chem125.webspace.yale.edu

the author is at j.mcbride@yale.edu

Comment: It appears that Yale University Prof. Emeritus McBride himself has provided the requested lecture files, etc.! Excellent! ;-)

Comment: @Ed V: Yes he has after my e-mail alerting him.

Answer (score 6):

There is a webpage called [Freshman Organic Chemistry I](https://oyc.yale.edu/chemistry/chem-125a) described as CHEM 125a. On the bottom of the page, there is a zip of all course pages $(\pu{10 MB})$. However, there are Terms of Use described in a separate page so you may need to donate money or pay for the usage. There is an age restriction as well:

> Use of Open Yale Courses website is restricted to those individuals over 18 years of age, emancipated minors, or those who possess legal parental or guardian consent, and are fully able and competent to enter into these terms, conditions, affirmations, representations and warranties herein. If you are under the age of 13, you may not use the Open Yale Courses website without consent or approval from your legal parent or guardian.

Yet, there is a section called "Sessions" just above this image:

[image]

If you click on the "Sessions", there are 37 lectures with appropriate 37 videos. There are also few exams and final exam. Enjoy the learning.